# How to edit current Billing and Shipping address in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs, checkout-page

How can I edit current Billing and shipping address and update the same address in customer address table?

Currently We are only adding a new address, but I need to edit current address and same edited field update on customer address entity table.

[image]